# What is wrong with my proof of the injectivity of the matrix exponential in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: proof-verification, matrix-exponential

We proved that for any quadratic matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, the derivative of $x(t) = e^{tA}$ is $x'(t) = Ae^{tA}$.

> Suppose we have two matrices $A,B$ such that $e^{tA} = e^{tB}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the derivatives of both functions must also be equal, i.e. $Ae^{tA} = Be^{tB} = Be^{tA}$. We then find $Ae^{tA}e^{-tA} = Be^{tA}e^{-tA}$ and since $e^{tA}e^{-tA} = I_n$, we obtain $A = B$.

This ought to show the injectivity of the matrix exponential, but I read that the matrix exponential is surjective (to the group of invertible matrices) but not injective. Pretty much all of the sites I visited involved things like Lie groups though and I'm still in my first year so I didn't understand much of what they were saying. Is the above proof correct or did I make any mistakes?

Comment: (In English we say *square* matrix.) Your argument is correct. If you assume equality for all $t$, then you deduce $A=B$. But if you only know that the equality holds, say, for $t\in\Bbb Z$, then what?

Comment: Your argument works if you require that the exponentials agree for every $t$. However just the exponential map is not injective: you can have $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2\pi \\ 2\pi & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and then $A \neq B$ but $\exp(A)=\exp(B)$. This argument didn't come from thin air, it came from complex numbers, where we identify $a+bi$ with $\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$ and we identify the matrix exponential with the complex exponential.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments: your proof is fine, but it doesn't prove the injectivity of the matrix exponential. What it proves is that if $e^{tA} = e^{tB}$ for all $t$ then $A = B$, but for injectivity the hypothesis you want is $e^A = e^B$, and there's nothing to differentiate.